# getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException!

Tags: c#, .net, image, save, undo

I am trying to paint the image and save it by using the mouse click event. I added a button to undo the last paint operation. I am performing this operation by loading the previously saved image by mouse click event. I have a code here... I'll show the part where i get the exception in comments in the code:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    rect.Width = 0;
    rect.Height = 0;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();

    pictureBox1.Image.Save(String.Format("{0}.Bmp",textBox2.Text )); //getting exception here!! 

    int radius = 10; //Set the number of pixel you want to use here

    //Calculate the numbers based on radius
    int x0 = Math.Max(e.X - (radius / 2), 0),
        y0 = Math.Max(e.Y - (radius / 2), 0),
        x1 = Math.Min(e.X + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Width),
        y1 = Math.Min(e.Y + (radius / 2), pictureBox1.Height);

    Bitmap bm = pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap; //Get the bitmap (assuming it is stored that way)
    for (int ix = x0; ix < x1; ix++)
    {
        for (int iy = y0; iy < y1; iy++)
        {
            bm.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color.Black); //Change the pixel color, maybe should be relative to bitmap
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Refresh(); //Force refresh
}
```

the code under button is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Load(string.Format("{0}.Bmp",textBox2.Text));
}
```

In my program I tried to save the image first and then painted it. When I click the button it is working & loading the image, but when I again tried to paint it, there I am getting the exception. Please help where I need to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to save the image to a file while the file is in use by the `pictureBox1.Image` object.

To simulate the problem:

```
string imageFilePath = string.Format("{0}.Bmp",textBox2.Text);

pictureBox1.Image.Save(imageFilePath);
pictureBox1.Load(imageFilePath);
pictureBox1.Image.Save(imageFilePath);//ExternalException will be thrown here.
```

Instead of using the same image file to keep the image previous state for undo, you can declare a private `Image` field and load image to it whenever loading, and save image to it instead of saving it to your `pictureBox1.Image` for undo.

However to implement a powerful multi-Undo/Redo, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503851/how-to-undo-the-paint-operation-using-c/6510292#6510292) is a good example that fits your case.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to declare a private image field and load image to it....as i need to undo ,upto one step back. please help with some code...i would be very happy!

Comment: `private Image _previousImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);`//just to avoid null, Now whenever you want to change image, save it first at the `_previousImage` field instead of file like `_previousImage = pictureBox1.Image.Clone() as Image`, and when you want to undo just load it from that field instead of the file like `pictureBox1.Image = _previousImage`. Hope that helps

Comment: .u mean to do me this way....pictureBox1.Image.Save("_previousImage.Bmp"); and then load the image picturebox1.load("_previousImage.Bmp");

Comment: @raghu: No, not save it to file that takes a performance, instead save it to a variable in the form class "in memory", `_previousImage` here is from type Image, just like `int foo = 0` `foo` is from type `int`. Reread the previous comment. A First line we declare an image variable not a string variable.